# Invalid 'PackageVersion' when using 'dotnet pack'

Tags: semantic-versioning, artifact, dotnet-cli

When using `dotnet pack` to create an artefact, the task is failing when one of the pre-release identifiers in my [SemVer](https://semver.org/) package version starts with `0`.

Is this a known bug with `dotnet pack`, and is there any fix for it?

```
1.0.8-INF-2382.9.088820
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.10.0+4242f381a for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.300/Sdks/NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack/build/NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(110,5): error MSB4018: The "GetPackOutputItemsTask" task failed unexpectedly. [/home/dgard/repos/ldx-analytics-infrastructure/.jenkins/ldx.analytics.infrastructure/ldx.analytics.infrastructure.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.300/Sdks/NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack/build/NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(110,5): error MSB4018: System.ArgumentException: PackageVersion string specified '1.0.8-INF-2382.9.088820' is invalid. [/home/dgard/repos/ldx-analytics-infrastructure/.jenkins/ldx.analytics.infrastructure/ldx.analytics.infrastructure.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.300/Sdks/NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack/build/NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(110,5): error MSB4018:    at NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.GetPackOutputItemsTask.Execute() [/home/dgard/repos/ldx-analytics-infrastructure/.jenkins/ldx.analytics.infrastructure/ldx.analytics.infrastructure.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.300/Sdks/NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack/build/NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(110,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() [/home/dgard/repos/ldx-analytics-infrastructure/.jenkins/ldx.analytics.infrastructure/ldx.analytics.infrastructure.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.300/Sdks/NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack/build/NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(110,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [/home/dgard/repos/ldx-analytics-infrastructure/.jenkins/ldx.analytics.infrastructure/ldx.analytics.infrastructure.csproj]
```

The error [`MSB4018`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/errors/msb4018?view=vs-2022) is pretty generic, but some Googling led me to [`NU5024`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu5024) which suggests that the version number is not SemVer compliant. However, I believe that it is valid, and online [SemVer checkers](https://jubianchi.github.io/semver-check/#/1/1.0.8-INF-2382.9.088820) seem to agree.

In this case, the portion that is causing the issue is `088820`, which is the first 6 characters of the Git commit hash, so it's not something that I can change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here seems to be that there is a bug with whatever package `dotnet` is using to validate that the `PackageVersion` is a valid SemVer version.

If using `<dot-separated pre-release identifiers>` and the following are all true for any identifier that follows a dot `.`, then the version is seen as not being valid SemVer.

- Starts with `0`.
- Is greater than one character in length.
- Does not contain any letters `[a-f]`.

For example, `1.0.8-INF-2382.9.088820` is invalid, but `1.0.8-INF-2382.9.0888a0` is valid.

The same is true when importing `SemVer` in Python. This fails -

```
print(semver.VersionInfo.parse(1.0.8-INF-2382.9.088820))
```

> ValueError: 1.0.8-INF-2382.9.088820 is not valid SemVer string

But this works -

```
print(semver.VersionInfo.parse(1.0.8-INF-2382.9.0888a0))
```

> 1.0.8-INF-2382.9.0888a0